# Mixed species space ship crew who are actually mind-controlled by one of the aliens who looks like a cat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once read a brilliant short story about a Mixed species space ship crew who are actually mind-controlled by one of the aliens who looks like a cat.  It is only when the alien cat becomes ill that the mind control breaks down and the crew start to act independently and the human crew member realises that they have been travelling around in the spaceship for years just to provide a home for the alien cat , the story ends with the cat regaining control and the human is used as an incubator for one of the other aliens (called a hippo or elephant?) who reproduced in the period when the mind controlled slipped and needs to deposit her eggs in someone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could this be one of the [Man-Kzin Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars) stories? The Kzinti were catlike aliens who had telepaths among them.

Comment: I remember this story as well - and thought it was a short story in a collection by either Ray Bradbury or Isaac Asimov but it could have been a collection of different writers. I can't recall

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215852/novel-where-a-group-of-scientists-in-a-spaceship-encounter-various-aliens (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

The events you describe are from [The Voyage of the Space Beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Space_Beagle) by A.E. van Vogt. Except the events are not connected; the alien cat and the creature that deposits the eggs in a human are from completely different chapters.